# How to get the device information (such as timezone, bluetooth status, Location information and so on) using Appium in real device

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios, xcrun

We are trying to automate iOS using Appium. In our scenario, we are getting lot of information from the device such as Bluetooth status, Battery Level, Location status, Latitude, Longitude, Device timezone and much more from the device. In Android we have adb commands to get all these information are there any commands for iOS to get all these device information. I have searched about XCRUN, iOS deploy but I couldn't find any commands related to that. Are there any Appium methods from Java client to get this information or any other commands? Kindly advice

Comment: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/system/system-time/